# How to build a multilingual website with Polymer?

Tags: html, polymer, multilingual, web-component

I don't want to duplicate my components or use templating application.
Then, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like the chrome.i18n api for chrome apps and extensions. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n the general idea is each language has a json file with all the text. sub foldered by language.

```
_locals
    \- en
     |  \- messages.json
     - es
         \- messages.json
```

content of the json file just needs to be valid json. nothing exciting just key value pairs

messages.json

```
{
  elementName: 'my-element',
  elementVersion: '0.1'
}
```

the user of the element could set the language with a attribute

```
<my-element language="en"></my-element>
```

then in your element you would make a XMLHttpRequest to get the text.

```
getLanguageText: function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = '/my-element/_locals/' + this.language + '/messages.json';
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    this.text = e.target.response;
  }.bind(this);
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.error('Error Loading Language Text', e);
  };
};
```

the real issue i guess with this approach is it being dependent on path of the json file staying static. not a real big deal if everyone is going to get the element from say bower where it will always be in the `bower_components/my-element/_locals/en/messages.json` location.

then you could use the values in your html just like any other polymer value.

```
{{text.elementName}}
```

maybe this will help. /shrug

edit: i didn't see this @ time of post but you might need to bind `this` to the onload callback. in the original answer `this` would be the xhr object. by using `.bind(this)` the callback would correctly target the custom element. ill edit answer.